# how to store image from buffer to file system in node.js using sharp.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

i am using sharp.js for image manipulation in node.js

my code

```
sharp(path)
        .toFormat('jpeg')
        .toBuffer((err, data, info) => {
            fs.writeFile(temp, buffer, { flag: 'w' }, function() {
                response.sendFile(temp);
            });
        });
```

here temp in fs means "the path" `var temp= imageDir + request.params.id;` ( http://localhost:2000/images/we.png )

1. upload image as png format or any other format
2. convert that image to `JPEG` using `.toFormat('jpeg')` and send to
   buffer
3. want to save that image from buffer to

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: Is this question complete? It looks like it's missing some things

Comment: @Geuis tryed but format was changing .,

Comment: You're going to need to provide sample code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @RobertMennell yes robert the question was complete one ., i converted the file but can't able to save them can you suggest a way to do so ?

Comment: @Geuis , question was updated

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't have 'buffer'. You should be writing data.

```
.toBuffer((err, data, info) => {
        fs.writeFile(temp, data, { flag: 'w' }, function() {
            response.sendFile(temp);
        });
    });
```

but you'd be better off using toFile instead of toBuffer:

```
sharp('originalFile.jpg').
        resize(330,null).
        flatten().
        toFile('newFile.jpg', function(err){
            if(err){
                response.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
            response.sendFile('newFile.jpg');
        });
```

Comment: thank you but ., what if i upload a jpg and convert to png ? .. file format was what ever we want .,

Comment: Then manipulate newFile.jpg to have the correct extension. If your variable `temp` already reflects the desired file type in its extension then just use that. Otherwise fix it.

Comment: okay so if i want to process a image with extension .webp to tiff ., okay the file name should not change the as of original name ., what if i can do ?

Comment: file name are of dynamic one ., then toFile are of too dynamic based on query parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
sharp(req.files[0].path).resize(400, 200).toFile('uploads/' + 'thumbnail-' + req.files[0].originalname, (err, sharp) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log(sharp);
            }
        });
```